# Expanding algebraic equations of polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, algebraic-equations

So suppose we have $G(z+h,w+t)$ where $G$ is an algebraic equation such that $G(z,w)=g_0(z)+g_1(z)w+\cdots+g_m(z)w^m$, each $g_i(z)$ is a polynomial of $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and $w$ is any function.

My textbook is telling me in a proof that $G(z+h,w+t)=G(z,w)+hG_z(z,w)+tG_w(z,w)+O(h^2+ht+t^2)$.

Can anyone elaborate why this is the case? Trying to expand does not seem fruitful to me.

Comment: $G(z,w)$ are build up by monomials of the form $z^m w^n$. Pick some small $m,n$, expand $G(z+h,w+t) = \cdots$ explicitly. Collect terms in the expansion which doesn't depend on $h,t$ and terms that depends on $h,t$ linearly. Compare them with $G(z,w), G_z(z,w)$ and $G_w(z,w)$. Do this a few times, the pattern should become obvious.

Comment: @achillehui I believe the result, but is there any obvious reason this is the case other than just noting the pattern and implying induction? A proof by induction seems nightmarish here.

Comment: No, you should not prove it. You should step back and recall what is the definition of $G_w$ and $G_z$. When you fix $z$ and $w$ and expand wrt $h$ and $t$. You get a polynomial in $h, t$. The definition of $G_z$ and $G_w$ is  a way to generalize the concept of coefficient of $h$ and $t$ under such an expansion.